# backup redis to mysql

Tags: mysql, persistence, redis, backup, replication

I want to backup my redis database to mysql.

What would be the best architecture?

I am thinking of the following:

1. Create a Slave for the Primary Database on a different server.
2. Write a Node.js application on top of the Slave to read all the data.
3. Create SQL queries and insert into the mysql database.

Is there any better way to do this? And how do I know when the Redis Slave instance is updated with data.

Comment: If you can't find an application that does this for you automatically, it does sound like a pretty significant project. The one thing we all want from backups is that they're reliable, so a roll-your-own that has bugs could be counter-productive. Do you intend to replicate to MySQL rather than back-up? Redis has a fairly robust backup system of its own.

Comment: Santosh - You asked the exact question on the redis-db mailing list about 20 hours before you posted on StackOverflow. Is there something that wasn't answered in that discussion thread? For reference, here is the mailing group discussion -  https://groups.google.com/d/topic/redis-db/qdVMl4_kgK8/discussion